# How to create a thumbnail from the middle of a video with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

how to generate thumbnail from the middle of video using ffmpeg..

e.g i have a video of duration 1 minute i want to generate thumbnail on 30th second

i have used the following code but it generate thumbnail at 59th second. i because i mention -ss 59 how can we make it dynamic to the middle of video duration.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -deinterlace -an -ss 59 -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s 256x160 output.jpg
```

i tried that but i am getting error no directory found.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -ss `ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d , | awk -F ':' '{print $3/2}'` output.jpg
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ffprobe` to get the duration of the input then use that to determine your `-ss` value.

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
30.24
```

Then script it however you prefer. Example using bash (I am not a PHP user so I can't give you a turnkey solution):

```
input=input.mp4
dur=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nk=1:nw=1 "$input")
ffmpeg -y -i "$input" -ss "$(echo "$dur / 2" | bc -l)" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 output.jpg
```

Comment: i need that in php. i want to use it in php 
like this

exec("E:/wamp/www/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i $video_path -deinterlace -an -ss 59 -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s 256x160 $thumb_path 2>&1");

Answer (score 0):

this is a more PHP Friendly way

`$dur = "ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nk=1:nw=1 $input";`

`$durt = system($dur);`

`$cmd = "ffmpeg -i $input -an -ss ".($durt/2)." -s 426x240 output.png";`

`system($cmd);`